# Narrowing LINQ query to one column

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to setup a query like this. So at first I'm selecting complete objects..

```
var values = (from p in Products
              where p.LockedSince == null
              select p);
```

Then optionally I'm adding extra `where`'s

```
if(SupplierId > 0)
    values = values.Where(p => p.SupplierId == SupplierId);
```

And in the end, I don't need the complete product objects anymore, I just need a simple distinct and ordered list of one column (`p.LocationName`) .. something like this:

```
values = values.Select( p.LocationName ).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

I've tried something like `Select(loc => new { p.LocationName })`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need intermediate results more effective way would be to write single query

```
var values = (from p in Products 
              where (p.LockedSince == null && (SupplierId <=0 || p.SupplierId == SupplierId))
              select p.LocationName).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Comment: It took me a minute before i fully understood how to read this, but now t seems logic, and it fits perfectly in my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
values = values.Select( p => p.LocationName ).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```